# Can we use Facelets in JSF1.1_02?

Tags: jsf, facelets

Can we use Facelets in JSF RI 1.1_02? If we can please send me some piece of code relating to that? Can anyone tell me which version of Tomcat will support Sun RI 1.1_02? I have a restriction of JSF 1.1 in my project, so if anyone know the thing related to this please share with me.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use Facelets in JSF1.1_02? If we can please send me some piece of code relating to that.

There was a problem at some time (see [Issue 300](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-300)) but as of Facelets 1.1.8, this is no longer the case as reported by Ryan Lubke in this [blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/facelets_and_sun_s_jsf1):

> I had previously blogged that Facelets wasn't quite working with Sun's
>   1.1_02 implementation of JSF 1.1.  I'm happy to report that as of Facelets 1.1.8, this is no longer the case.  Facelets will work with 1.1_01, 1.1_02, and our recent 1.2 release.

To use Facelets, make sure the Facelets JAR (jsf-facelets.jar) is in your project's classpath and add a single modification to your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<faces-config>
  <application>
    <!-- tell JSF to use Facelets -->
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

And make JavaServer Faces defaults to `.xhtml` for views in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

> Can anyone tell me which version of tomcat will support Sun RI1.1_02?

JSF 1.1 runs fine on Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6.0.